# how to create md5 hash of a column in R?

Tags: r, md5

I have a data frame

```
ID, VID
 1 , xyz-0001
```

I would like to replace `VID` with md5 hash of `VID` column value.

How would i do that in R? I looked at `digest` package but can not figure out how to put that in R Code

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Package `digest` absolutely suitable for this task, so firstly we load it:

```
library(digest)
```

Then create/load/etc. test `data.frame` `df`:

```
txt <-
"ID,VID
1,xyz-0001
2,abc-0987"

df <- read.table(header=T, text=txt, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=F)
df
```

The initial data looks like:

```
  ID      VID
1  1 xyz-0001
2  2 abc-0987
```

Then we can use function `digest` with specified algorithm:

```
df$VID <- sapply(df$VID, digest, algo="md5")
df
```

Now we have hashed column `VID` in `df`:

```
  ID                              VID
1  1 44e3a9cf85f802ef50f18e64e01c5e32
2  2 c576ff180b2046c1a3ae939766588fd3
```

Answer (score 33):

With an addition to redmode's answer:

```
library(digest)
txt <- "hello world"
hash <- digest(txt, algo="md5", serialize=F)
hash
```

> [1] "5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3"

Setting serialize option to FALSE makes your results consistent with what you would get from online hash generators such as [this](http://www.md5hashgenerator.com) or [this](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php).

Comment: Simplest answer and I can confirm this worked out-of-the-box with no fuss. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 23):

Another option is install the `openssl` package and use its MD5 hashing function. It's a vectorised function so unlike with `digest` so you won't have to use sapply on it.

```
library(openssl)

df$VID <- md5(df$VID)
```

This will replace the characters in the VID column with their MD5 hashed equivalents.

**Note:** This function requires data to be a character type so if you want to use this on a column of integers you will need to convert them to characters with the `as.character` function first.