# How to reorder a vector so that consecutive integers are not next to one another?

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of integers `x`

```
x = c(1:3,6:7)
```

I need to reorder `x` such that if any consecutive integers are present in `x`, they are not next to one another (if possible at all). Right now I have a loop. Is there a better way?

Values in `x` will not necessarily be unique. But for now you can assume that arranging `x` in the way I want will always be possible (*I actually need to find out a way to determine if `x` can be arranged the way I mentioned above, but that may be a second question by itself*).

```
set.seed(42)
while(any(abs(diff(x)) == 1)){
    x = sample(x)
    print(x)
}
#[1] 7 6 1 2 3
#[1] 1 3 7 6 2
#[1] 7 2 6 1 3
```

Comment: Can we assume the x values are unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more R style way:

```
myfunc <- function(y) {
    yt <- table(y)
    yt <- structure(.Data=as.vector(yt), .Names=names(yt))
    ys <- sort(as.numeric(names(yt)))
    ys <- c(ys[seq(1,length(ys),2)],ys[seq(2,length(ys),2)])
    result <- lapply(ys, function(i) rep(i,yt[as.character(i)]))
    result <- do.call(c, result)
    return(result)
}

res <- myfunc(c(1,5,7,8,3,7,9,2,6,3,87,7,3,1,1,1,3))
print(res)
[1]  1  1  1  1  3  3  3  3  6  8 87  2  5  7  7  7  9

print(any(abs(diff(res)) == 1))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Also, a vector can always be sorted in the way you want if it doesn't have only 3 or 2 consecutive unique integers.  So 7,8 and 3,4,4,5 can never be sorted, but anything else that doesn't follow that pattern can be sorted.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility off the top of my head: a slightly modified bubble sort where you swap if `x[j] + 1 == x[j + 1]`:

```
# Bubble sort implementation from: 
# https://www.r-bloggers.com/bubble-sorting-in-r-c-and-julia-code-improvements-and-the-r-compiler/
bubble_sort = function(vec) {
    no_passes = 0
    while(1) {
        no_swaps = 0
        for (j in 1 : (length(vec) - 1 - no_passes)) {
            if (vec[j] + 1 == vec[j + 1]) {
                s = vec[j]
                vec[j] = vec[j+1]
                vec[j+1] = s
                no_swaps = no_swaps + 1
            }
        }
        no_passes = no_passes + 1
        if(no_swaps == 0) break
    }
    vec
}

x = c(1:3,6:7)
bubble_sort(x)
```

This has time-complexity `O(N^2)`, but what you are doing now is essentially a bogosort, which is `O(N!)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work perfectly (`7` and `6` are next to one another). But I like the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a solution from my earlier comment:

1. Hash each of the elements of the vector with the simplest hash that has sufficient [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion) for your input field, and store those in another output vector. It looks like R has the [digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686645/how-to-create-md5-hash-of-a-column-in-r) library for this job.
2. Sort the output vector in increasing/decreasing order, and store the vector of reordered indices, which R will give you with `sort()`.
3. Index the original vector with the reordered indices.

Most hash functions are designed to change drastically with a single alteration in the output, so `md5(1)` should not be consecutive to `md5(2)`, with high probability:

```
$ echo 1 | md5
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1

$ echo 2 | md5
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
```

As mentioned in the comments, this depends on the elements of the vector being unique. If they are not, add a random number to the element just before you hash it. You may also want to fuzz your inputs especially if you have a small set, as Marius mentions in the comments:

```
> y = 1:5; y[order(sapply(y, function (n) { digest(n + runif(1), "md5")}))]
[1] 5 1 3 2 4
> y = 1:5; y[order(sapply(y, function (n) { digest(n + runif(1), "md5")}))]
[1] 2 5 4 1 3
```

Assuming the hash function has constant-time insertion, this will run in `O(n)` time.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the desired ordering does it? If you have `1, 2, 3`, there's no guarantee that say `hash(1) < hash(3) < hash(2)` rather than `hash(1) < hash(2) < hash(3)`

Comment: @Marius Did I misread the question? I thought the requirement was just that consecutive elements don't end up next to each other.

Comment: I think your solution makes that likely but doesn't guarantee it. Of course you could run a quick check after trying it, then if it fails add random numbers to each elements and try again.

Comment: See `y = 1:5; y[order(sapply(y, function (n) { digest(n, "md5")}))]` for an example of this failing.

Comment: Oh yes, this is definitely a stochastic guarantee. I don't think it works for small sets, or sets larger than the space of the hash.

Comment: @bright-star Interesting idea, but it fails over 50% of the time on y=1:5, which is just as bad as random.